# Процедура pl/sql

Tags: plsql, procedure

Есть одна процедура, у которой входные параметры это `varchar` данные,
разделенных пробелом.
Эту процедуру я вызываю внутри другой процедуры.

Внутри процедуры есть такие запросы:

```
BEGIN
          SELECT xxxx INTO g011_level_code FROM xxxxx WHERE
          xxxx=4314 and xxxx like '%'||LOWER(i.g011)||'%' and (to_date('01.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY') between beg_date and  nvl(end_date,to_date('01.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY')));
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
          g011_level_code := 123;  
        END;
```

В этом запросе я записываю в переменную `g011_level_code`. Потом эту переменную и еще такие же переменные пытаюсь добавить в процедуру с входным параметром `varchar`:

```
BEGIN
          v_result := xxxx_procedure(
            '67 146 846 1208 2972',
            i.g011_level_code,--  и еще какие то переменные
            123653,
            to_date('01.01.2015','DD.MM.YYYY')
          );
          dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
```

Но при выполнении ругается, что так нельзя. Можно как-то решить это или надо поменять подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Процедуры в oracle не имеют возвращаемого значения, поэтому нельзя написать `v_result := xxxx_procedure`. Есть два пути решения:

Сделать не процедуру, а функцию, которая вернет нужное значение:

```
create or replace function xxxx_procedure(параметры)
 return number
is
 g011_level_code number;
begin
  SELECT xxxx INTO g011_level_code ...;
  ...
  return(g011_level_code);
end;
/

begin
 v_result := xxxx_procedure(...);
 -- Если так не выйдет, то:
 -- select xxxx_procedure(...) into v_result from DUAL;
end;
```

Или использовать процедуру с возвращаемыми параметрами:

```
create or replace procedure xxxx_procedure(параметры, g011_level_code out number) is
begin
  SELECT xxxx INTO g011_level_code ...;
end;
/

begin
 xxxx_procedure(...,v_result); -- Значение будет записано в параметр
end;
```